# How to partial conj?

Tags: clojure, currying, partial-application

I'm trying to create a function that applies several processes to a map, including adding / updating some standard items to each map using "conj". I'm doing it by composing several other functions using "comp".

So I tried doing this

```
(defn everything [extra] (comp (partial conj {:data extra}) another-func) )
```

Which won't work because conj wants the extra data as the second argument, not the first.

I assume there should be a similarly straightforward way of composing a curried conj, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Comment: `#(conj % {:data extra})` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes ... perfectly ... didn't think of it. :-)

Comment: ...then I'll make it an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is just to write an anonymous function:

```
(defn everything [extra]
  (comp #(conj % {:data extra}) another-func))
```